# Mostrar Div e ocultar outras que estão visiveis com 2 arrays no JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, funções

Eu possuo o seguinte código baseado em `JavaScript`:

```
var perguntas = new Array();
var respostas = new Array();
var totalPerguntas = 2;

perguntas[1] = "Pergunta um";
respostas[1] = "Resposta um";
perguntas[2] = "Pergunta dois";
respostas[2] = "Resposta dois";

function listaPerguntas() {

    for (var i = 1; i <= totalPerguntas; i++) {
        var frasePergunta = perguntas[i];
        var fraseResposta = respostas[i];

        document.write("<div id='classPergunta'><div id='frasePergunta'><h2>" + frasePergunta + "</h2></div>" + "<br>" + "<div id='fraseResposta'><h4>" + fraseResposta + "</h4></div></div>" + "<br>");

    }
}

function mudarEstado() {
    document.getElementById("classPergunta").style.display = "block";
}

document.write(listaPerguntas())
document.write("<br><br><button type='button' onclick='mudarEstado('perguntas[i].respostas[i]')' >Next</button>");
```

Basicamente, ele pega o `Array` e retorna as perguntas guardadas nelas ao clique do botão. O que eu procuro é uma solução para fazer um conjunto de perguntas e respostas que ao clique ele avance para a próxima pergunta e esconda as demais `divs` de maneira que isso seja aplicado as DUAS `ARRAYS`, eu achei um código que basicamente faz o que eu gostaria, mas um pouco diferente e apenas com uma array, então não consegui prosseguir. Aceito criticas construtivas pois estou treinando !

Answer (score 0):

A estrutura do seu código está um pouco errada, será complicado pra você conseguir uma solução cabível com essa estrutura, vamos lá:

- Primeiramente você está escrevendo o resultado da função `listaPerguntas()` novamente, desde que a mesma já está ultilizando `document.write` , ou seja, você está escrevendo o valor impresso do HTML duas vezes.
- Existem divs com o nome mesmo `id` , ID's em elementos em HTML são únicas, logo devem ser ultilizadas em apenas 1 elemento.
- Da maneira que está usando as arrays: `perguntas[1] e respostas[1]` você sempre perderá o primeiro item da array, pois arrays começam em 0. ex: `perguntas[0] = Primeira Pergunta`
- O total de perguntas deve ser relacionado ao tamanho da array, ao invés de ser o total estático em uma variável. Use `perguntas.length` ao invés de total_perguntas. Assim quando uma nova pergunta for adicionada a sua array, o total também será atualizado.
- É uma boa prática adicionar as respostas dentro de um objeto da mesma pergunta, sendo assim você entra em um loop apenas em uma array ao invés de duas.

A solução pro seu problema é criar uma função que liste as perguntas e um contador para que pagine entre as perguntas. Basicamente assim:

```js
let perguntas = new Array();
let respostas = new Array();
let contador = -1;

const container = document.querySelector('.perguntas-respostas');

perguntas.push( { pergunta: 'Pergunta um', respostas: ['Resposta 1' , 'Resposta 1-2'] } );
perguntas.push( { pergunta: 'Pergunta dois', respostas: ['Resposta 2' , 'Resposta 2-1'] } );

const listaPerguntas = () => { 
 perguntas.forEach( (val) => { 
   // para performance é melhor criar elements, mas aqui pro exemplo vamos fazer com strings
   let str = '<div class="pergunta"><strong>' + val.pergunta + '</strong><br />';
   val.respostas.forEach( (res) => str += (res + '<br />') );
   str += '</div>';
   container.innerHTML += str;
 });
}

listaPerguntas();

const mudaEstado = () => { 
 if(contador === (perguntas.length-1)) contador = 0;
 else if(contador >= -1) contador++;

 showPergunta();
}

const showPergunta = () => { 
 const perguntasEl = container.querySelectorAll('.pergunta');
 console.log(contador);
 //console.log(perguntasEl);
 perguntasEl.forEach( (v) => v.style.opacity = .2 );
 perguntasEl[contador].style.opacity = 1;
}

mudaEstado();
```

```css
.pergunta { 
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onClick="mudaEstado()">Next</button>
<div class="perguntas-respostas">

</div>
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Ajudou sim ! Muito obrigado pela sua contribuição e por compartilhar sua critica comigo !